# Django share unpicklable objects between requests

Tags: django

I am currently working on a Django project that will hopefully make some transformations to videofiles thru the web. To make the transformation to the videos, I am using opencv's python API and I am also uing Dajax to perform ajax requests.

In the ajax requests file i have the following code:

```
    @dajaxice_register
    def transform_and_show(request, filename, folder, frame_count, img_number):
        detector = Detector(filename) //Object which uses opencv API
        dajax = Dajax()
        generated_file = detector.detect_people_by_frame(folder, str(img_number))
        dajax.assign('#video', 'src', '/media/generated'+folder+generated_file)
        return dajax.json()
```

The idea is to tranform videos frame by frame and to display each transformed frame in the browser in an img tag giving the sensation to the user that he/she is watching the transformed video, so this method is called in a javascript loop.

The problem is that in this approach, the object "detector" is reinitialized in every iteration so it only generates the image corresponding to the first frame of the video. My idea was to workaround this issue by making "detector" persistent between requests so that the pointer to the next frame of the video wouldn't be set to 0 on every request. 
The problem is that Dectector object is not picklable, meaning that it cannot be cached or saved to a session object.

Is there anything I can do to make it persistent between requests?

NOTE: I have considered using HTTP push approaches like APE or Orbit but since this is just an investigation project there is no real concern about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a module level variable to store the object?

Make "detector" a global at the file level.

```
detector = None

def transform():
    global detector
    if detector is None:
        detector = Detector(filename)
    file = detector.detect(....)
```

Comment: Make "djax" a global at the file level.